# Python Scrapy XPathSelector

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to crawl data from a site using scrapy crawler. How to get `<meta itemprop="rvalue" content="4.0">` content value using select()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
item['key'] = xpath.select('//meta[@itemprop="rvalue"]/@content').extract()
```

It'll return a list, so process it with an item loader.